# Accessing custom view with findViewById

Tags: java, android

I have a custom `EditText` set up in its own file `CustomEditText.java`:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    ...
}
```

I reference it in my activity's XML with the full name:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <com.example.app.CustomEditText
        ...
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use my custom EditText by putting this in my activity class:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    CustomEditText customEditText = new CustomEditText(this, null);

    linearLayout.addView(customEditText);
    this.setContentView(linearLayout);
```

I can access this `customEditText` normally:

```
customEditText.setText("Hello!")
```

But I can't access this `customEditText` later on with `findViewById(R.id.customEditText)` as this returns an empty `EditText`.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you putting two `CustomEditText` into your layout? By putting one in the XML and adding another one in the Activity? Also where do you set the ID `customEditText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the view in XML, you don't need to add it programmatically with

```
CustomEditText customEditText = new CustomEditText(this, null);
linearLayout.addView(customEditText);
```

Set `android:id="@+id/customEditText` on your CustomEditText in xml and you will be able to find the view using `findViewById(R.id.customEditText)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that fixed it. If you have the the time, could you answer hypothetically if I did have two views and I had to access the one created programmatically

Comment: Yep, if you add a view programmatically, you can call View.setId(NEW_ID) and use findViewById(NEW_ID) to access it.